# Resize Accordion Menu jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to `jQuery`, and building an accordion Menu.

My problem is, I have the menu and I would like to make it a fixed size, so I want it so that whenever you hover over one of the items, it enlarges and the other options shrink.

I can not figure out how to do this. I have tried setting a `max-width` and setting a `width`, but what it does is it puts some of the div's below the others to make them all fit. I want everything on the same line and the div's to each shrink by a certain amount.

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#accordion > li').hover(
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'width':'400px'},500);
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                },
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);

                    $this.stop().animate({'width':'100px'},1000);
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: please add html code too, A fiddle will be great to get started with. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bj3dpyok/  I am trying to get the animation and flow of this http://mottie.github.io/Kwicks/#ex6 but I dont know how to add it in with my current project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. A per perfect answer for you
**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Elegant Accordion with jQuery and CSS3</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Elegant Accordion with jQuery and CSS3" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, slide out,accordion, css3, fadeout, fadein, elegant, fancy, box shadow"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <style>
            *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            body{
                font-family:Arial;
                background:#fff url(pattern.png) repeat top left;
            }
            a{
                color:#444;
            }
            a:hover{
                color:#999;
            }
            .title{
                width:500px;
                height:152px;
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                background:transparent url(title.png) no-repeat top left;
            }
            a.back{
                background:transparent url(back.png) no-repeat top left;
                position:fixed;
                width:150px;
                height:27px;
                outline:none;
                bottom:0px;
                left:0px;
            }
            #content{
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            .reference{
                clear:both;
                top:300px;
                left:0px;
                position:absolute;
                text-align:right;
                width:400px;
                padding:20px;
                background-color:#fff;
                -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #ddd;
                -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #ddd;
                box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #ddd;
            }
            .reference p a{
                text-transform:uppercase;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
                color:#666;
                text-decoration:none;
                font-size:10px;
            }
            .reference p a:hover{
                color:#333;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <a class="back" href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/26/elegant-accordion-with-jquery-and-css3/"></a>
            <div class="title"></div>
            <div class="reference">
                <p><a href="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/view_photog.php?photogid=901">Image 1: Michelle Meiklejohn / FreeDigitalPhotos.net</a></p>
                <p><a href="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/view_photog.php?photogid=879">Image 2: Luigi Diamanti / FreeDigitalPhotos.net</a></p>
                <p><a href="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/view_photog.php?photogid=503">Image 3: Tina Phillips / FreeDigitalPhotos.net</a></p>
                <p><a href="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/view_photog.php?photogid=1039">Image 4: Ahmet Guler / FreeDigitalPhotos.net</a></p>
            </div>


            <ul class="accordion" id="accordion">
                <li class="bg1">
                    <div class="heading">Guler</div>
                    <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>Guler</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                            ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                            nulla pariatur.</p>
                        <a href="#">more &rarr;</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="bg2">
                    <div class="heading">Phillips</div>
                    <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>Phillips</h2>
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
                            accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa
                            quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                            dicta sunt explicabo. </p>
                        <a href="#">more &rarr;</a>
                    </div>

                </li>
                <li class="bg3">
                    <div class="heading">Diamanti</div>
                    <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>Diamanti</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                            ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                            nulla pariatur.</p>
                        <a href="#">more &rarr;</a>
                    </div>

                </li>
                <li class="bg4 bleft">
                    <div class="heading">Meiklejohn</div>
                    <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>Meiklejohn</h2>
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
                            accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa
                            quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                            dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
                            sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni
                            dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                        <a href="#">more &rarr;</a>
                    </div>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- The JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#accordion > li').hover(
                    function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.stop().animate({'width':'480px'},500);
                        $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                        $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                        $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    },
                    function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.stop().animate({'width':'115px'},1000);
                        $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                        $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                        $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.accordion{
    list-style:none;   
    position:absolute;
    right:80px;
    top:0px;
    font-family: Cambria, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
ul.accordion li{
    float:right;
    width:115px;
    height:480px;
    display:block;
    border-right:2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
    box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
}
ul.accordion li.bg1{
    background-image:url(../images/1.jpg);
}
ul.accordion li.bg2{
    background-image:url(../images/2.jpg);
}
ul.accordion li.bg3{
    background-image:url(../images/3.jpg);
}
ul.accordion li.bg4{
    background-image:url(../images/4.jpg);
}
ul.accordion li.bleft{
    border-left:2px solid #fff;
}
ul.accordion li .heading{
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:60px;
    opacity:0.9;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#444;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #ccc;
}
ul.accordion li .description{
    position:absolute;
    width:480px;
    height:175px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
ul.accordion li .description h2{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:45px;
    color:#444;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0px 0px 15px 20px;
    text-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #ccc;
}
ul.accordion li .description p{
    line-height:14px;
    margin:10px 22px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
ul.accordion li .description a{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    left:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#888;
}
ul.accordion li .description a:hover{
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

ul.accordion li .bgDescription{
    background:transparent url(../images/bgDescription.png) repeat-x top left;
    height:340px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}
```

Select and put the images of your choice....ok.

Comment: it was just showing plain html no script or style showed up

Comment: It worked, but what I am trying to achieve is a mix between http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/26/elegant-accordion-with-jquery-and-css3/ and http://mottie.github.io/Kwicks/#ex6

Comment: I just want an accordion menu that looks ecmxactly like the one in the first link, but I want the accordion menu to stay the same height weather there is a tab open or not. So when one tab is open the others shrink to make the whole thing the same size as it is when they are all closed. Does this make sense?

Comment: So, what else you want in this code?..You said like the first link right?

Comment: My problem is that I want the whole accordion menu to never get past the size of 448 so that when one tab is expand on hover. The other's shrink by a certain factor to keep the whole accordion menu the same size. Thanks for the help.